# Difference between MOV r/m8,r8 and MOV r8,r/m8

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code, opcode

By looking at intel volume of instructions, I found this:

1) `88 /r     MOV r/m8,r8`
2) `8A /r     MOV r8,r/m8`

When I write a line like this in NASM, and assemble it with the listing option:

`mov al, bl`

I get this in the listing:

`88D8    mov al, bl`

So obviously NASM chosed the first instruction of the two above, but isn't the second instruction an option two? if so, on what basis did NASM chosed the first?

Comment: No specific reason, it just has to pick something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two encodings exist because a modr/m byte can only encode one memory operand. So to allow both `mov r8,m8` and `mov m8,r8`, two encodings are needed. Of course, this way we can encode uses of `mov` with both operands being registers using either encoding and `nasm` just picks one at random. There is no special reason for the choice and I have seen assemblers make different choices.

I have also heard about an assembler that watermarked binaries it assembles by choosing an instruction encoding in a specific way. This way the author of the assembler could track down and sue people who used his assembler without paying.

Comment: I've heard that too, I don't really remember what I heard it about.. was it HLA?

Comment: I think it was as86 but so far cant find the right hit online, I have a (dot matrix) printed manual at home if I can find it...

Comment: Apparently it was A86

Answer (score 8):

Interesting side effect of having different encodings:  From the A86 manual.

> 6. A86 takes advantage of situations in which more than one set    of opcodes can be generated for the same instruction.  (For    example,
>      MOV AX,BX can be generated using either an 89 or 8B    opcode, by
>      reversing fields in the following effective address    byte.  Both
>      forms are absolutely identical in functionality    and execution
>      speed.)  A86 adopts an unusual mix of choices in    such situations. 
>      This creates a code-generation "footprint"    that occupies no space
>      in your program file, but will enable    me to tell, and to
>      demonstrate in a court of law, if a    non-trivial object file has
>      been produced by A86. The    specification for this "footprint" is
>      sufficiently obscure and    complicated that it would be impossible to
>      duplicate by    accident.  I claim exclusive rights to the particular 
>      "footprint" I have chosen, and prohibit anyone from    duplicating it.
>      This has at least two specific implications:
>
>    a. Any assembler that duplicates the "footprint" is mine.  If
>        it is not identified as mine and issued under these terms,
>        then those who sell or distribute the assembler will be
>        subject to prosecution.
>
>    b. Any program marked with the "footprint" has been produced
>        by my assembler.  It is subject to condition 5 above.

Answer (score 5):

As [Harold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335265/difference-between-mov-r-m8-r8-and-mov-r8-r-m8#comment75674468_44335265) pointed out: there is no reason.
Maybe the authors found the use of a forward move more appealing than a reverse move or maybe they just picked up the first opcode.

I took a look at the NASM source code and found out that the encoding is done essentially with a big lookup table so it is really a matter of taste.
Using the other opcode (8AC3) would have simplified the code (I guess) if the parsing had not used a lookup table: instructions like `addps` are asymmetric and by using `8A /r` for `mov al, bl` the code could be reused to compute the ModR/M byte for `addps` and similar instructions too. `addps xmm0, xmm3` use the same ModR/M byte (C3) as `mov al, bl` when the `8A /r` is used.
Note that the registers `A` (`B`) and `xmm0` (`xmm0`) are encoded with the same numbers.

It is still fun, however, to figure out why there are two encodings.

---

As [Mark Hopkins (re)discovered, the earlier x86 instructions encoding make a lot more sense in octal](http://www.dabo.de/ccc99/www.camp.ccc.de/radio/help.txt).
A byte in octal has three digits that I'll call G P F (Group, oPeration, Flags).

G is the octal group, instructions in the same group tend to perform similar tasks (e.g. arithmetic vs moves).
However, this is not a strict division.
P is the operation; for example, in the arithmetic group an operation is the subtraction and another is the addition.
F is a bitset used to control the behaviour of the operation. Each group and operation use the digit F as they please, it may not even be a bit set (for example G=2, P=7 is `mov r16, imm16` and F is used to select `r16`).

For the `mov` instructions that move from memory/register into a register or the other way around the G is 2 and P is 1.
The F is a 3-bit field with semantic:

```
  2   1   0    bit
+---+---+---+
| s | d | b |
+---+---+---+

s = 1 if moving to/from a segment register
    0 if moving to/from a gp register

d = 1 if moving mem -> reg
    0 if moving mem <- reg

b = 1 if moving a WORD
    0 if moving a BYTE
```

We can begin to form opcodes but we still miss a way to select the operands.

```
G=2, P=1, F={s=0, d=0, b=0} 210 (88) mov r/m8, r8
G=2, P=1, F={s=0, d=0, b=1} 211 (89) mov r/m16, r16
G=2, P=1, F={s=0, d=1, b=0} 212 (8A) mov r8, r/m8
G=2, P=1, F={s=0, d=1, b=1} 213 (8B) mov r16, r/m16
G=2, P=1, F={s=1, d=0, b=0} 214 (8C) mov r/m16, Sreg
G=2, P=1, F={s=1, d=0, b=1} 215 (8D) Not a move, segment registers are 16-bit
G=2, P=1, F={s=1, d=1, b=0} 216 (8E) mov Sreg, r/m16
G=2, P=1, F={s=1, d=1, b=1} 217 (8F) Not a move, segment registers are 16-bit
```

After the opcode it must come the ModR/M byte, it is used to select the addressing mode and the register.

The ModR/M byte can be regarded, in octal, as three fields: X R M.

X and M are combined together to form the addressing mode.
R selects the register (e.g. 0 = A, 3 = B).

One of the addressing mode (X=3, M=any) lets us address the registers (through M) and not the memory.
For example, X=3, R=0, M=3 (C3) sets the register B as the "memory" operand and the register A as the register operand.
While X=3, R=3, M=0 (D8) sets the register A as the "memory" operand and the register B as the register operand.

Here we can see where the ambiguity lies: the ModR/M byte lets us encode a source register and a destination register. Meanwhile, the opcode let us encode a move from the source to the destination or from the destination to the source - this gives us the freedom to choose which register is what.

For example, suppose we want to move B into A.

If we settle on A as the register operand (source) and B as the memory operand (destination) then the ModR/M byte is X=3, R=0, M=3 (C3).
To move from B to A, as in your example, using the lower 8 bits only, we encode the move as
G=2, P=1, F={s=0,d=1,b=0} (8A) because we move mem->reg (B->A). 
Thus the final instruction is 8AC3.

If we choose A as the memory operand (destination) and B as the register operand (source) the ModR/M byte is X=3, R=3, M=0 (D8).
The move is G=2, P=1, F={s=0,d=0,b=0} (88) because we move reg->mem (B->A).
The final instruction is 88D8.

If we want to move the whole 16-bit register (we ignore operand size prefixes here) we just set the b bit of F:

G=2, P=1, F={s=0,d=1,b=1} for the first case, leading to 8BC3.
G=2, P=1, F={s=0,d=0,b=1} for the second case, leading to 89D8.

You can check this out with `ndisasm`

```
00000000  8AC3              mov al,bl
00000002  88D8              mov al,bl
00000004  8BC3              mov ax,bx
00000006  89D8              mov ax,bx
```

Comment: thank's for the effort and explanations, the link might be useful for me in the future too.

Comment: @BiteBytes My pleasure. I also answer as a way to clear my mind and for other readers, It's not really an effort :)