# Encodings specialized for AL register?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

Unlike the other registers, I've noticed doing something like `add $1, %al` encodes the instruction much differently than the other (8-bit) registers. For example:

```
add $3, %al
add $3, %bl
add $3, %cl
add $3, %dl
```

Translates to:

```
0x0000000000401000  04 03     ? add    $0x3,%al
0x0000000000401002  80 c3 03  ? add    $0x3,%bl
0x0000000000401005  80 c1 03  ? add    $0x3,%cl
0x0000000000401008  80 c2 03  ? add    $0x3,%dl
```

I went through the encoding of add-imm8 in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255426/simple-instruction-encode), but the `add $3, %al` seems to completely contradict that (no mod-reg-rm byte?). Is this a legacy instruction or something, or why does it look so much different than the other ones?

Comment: [Instruction Lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4567903) mentions the AL, imm8 short form encodings that exist for most ALU instructions, along with various other short-form encodings.  Yes, these date back to 8086, just like the modrm encodings, so these are *all* part of x86's 8086 legacy.

Comment: See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160739) - that answer of mine on that question has a section about 8086 history / design decisions.  8086 definitely favoured using AL/AX as "the accumulator", hence the name, providing special short-forms for it.